# Start new activity with PageAdapter

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-pageradapter

I am developing an android app, in which there are 4 different tabs. Now with each tab, I've to assign different activity. e.g. Say with tab 1, there should be First.java activity. With tab 2, there should be Second.java activity and so on. I've followed one tutorial and implemented successfully, below is my code,

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener{  
    private TabHost host;  
    private ViewPager pager; 

 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
   host = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  
   pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  

   host.setup();  


   TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("tab1");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);  
   spec.setIndicator("Check In");   
   host.addTab(spec);  

   spec = host.newTabSpec("tab2");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);  
   spec.setIndicator("Buddies");  
   host.addTab(spec);  

   spec = host.newTabSpec("tab3");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);  
   spec.setIndicator("Recommendation");  
   host.addTab(spec); 

   spec = host.newTabSpec("tab4");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab4);  
   spec.setIndicator("Feed");  
   host.addTab(spec);  

   pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));  
   pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);  
   host.setOnTabChangedListener(this);  

 }  
    @Override  
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId){  
         int pageNumber = 0;  
         if(tabId.equals("tab1"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 0;  

         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab2"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 1;  
         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab3"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 2;  
         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab4"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 3;  
         }
         else
         {  
              pageNumber = 3;  
         }  

         pager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);  
    } 

    @Override  
    public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {  
         host.setCurrentTab(pageNumber);  
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


    }
    }
```

### MyPagerAdapter.java

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context ctx;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TextView tView = new TextView(ctx);
        position++;
        tView.setText("Page number: " + position);
        tView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tView.setTextSize(20);
        container.addView(tView);
        return tView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

But, here I want to start different activity with each tab, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context ctx;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View parent_view = null;
        if (position ==0) {
            parent_view = getViewForPageOne();
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(parent_view, 0);
            return parent_view;
        }


        else
        {
            TextView tView = new TextView(ctx);
            position++;
            tView.setText("Page number: " + position);
            tView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            tView.setTextSize(20);
            container.addView(tView);

            return tView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    private View getViewForPageOne(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService
                  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, null);

         return v;
    }
}
```

And here you can change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using buttons, instead of tabs with PageAdapter, then you only need to call `OnClickListener()` indicating the page you need to change, for example: in the first button, you call first page, `pager.setCurrentItem(0);`

Comment: Ya but this is not my question. I want different activities in different tabs. Means in tab 1, there should be activity A; in tab 2 , there should be activity B and like wise....